# Very simple Angular directive using restrict to 'C' not working

Tags: angularjs, class, angular-directive

I'm doing a very simple directive, this is the **app.js** code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

myApp.directive('layout-top', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        templateUrl: 'templates/layout__top.template.html'
    }
})
```

This is the template to load:

```
<div class="layout__top">
    <div class="top__left">
        Some kind of content
    </div>
</div>
```

And thi, is the html code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="layout__wrapper">
            <!-- TOPBAR GOES HERE -->
            <div class="layout-top"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I try using restric to A or E it works, but not with class. Why?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 

    <div class="layout-top"></div>

?

Comment: I think Caleb might be right, the underscore should be a hyphen...

Comment: is a double underscore also, would work with single

Comment: Instead of `__`(double underscore) it should `_`(single underscore) like `class="layout_top"` directive normalization process will take care of it.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled the code. Now is correct and still won't work.

Comment: Now you changed directive name away from what it should have been .. it was right before with camelCase

Comment: @charlietfl If I use something like `layoutTop` Chrome freezes... o_0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT use `class="layout-top"` twice ( once in your template and once in your HTML code)

Change your class inside your template from `class="layout-top"` to `class="layout-top-tmp"`

Comment: good catch...OP  changed the code in question ... it got confusing .. fresh eyes helped

Comment: @NicolasHumbert You are right! Is this because of the name conversion `layout__top` is converted to `layoutTop` ?

Comment: But if I use `layout-top` or `layout__top` it's give me an error... it literally freezes the browser. It's possible that internally Angular converts `_` or `-` to camelCase?

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas is right about the duplicate call.

But shouldnt the name of the directive be "layoutTop" in the directive declaration?

```
myApp.directive('layoutTop', (...))
```

Comment: Was it the problem ??

Comment: Sorry I can't type today :( The problem was the `layout__top` in the template, that gets converted to `layoutTop` by Angular and conflicts with the `layoutTop` in the html part. It got confusing because I typed the answer wrong several times. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

you have

```
  <div class="layout-top"></div>
```

you need

```
<div layout-top></div>
```

Comment: no...OP is using `restrict:'C'` ... you are showing `restrict:'A'`

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly... I want to restrict it to the class... Restricting it to A or E works, but I want to try Class...